# AWS Code Star Express API Enable CORS and Integration Response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation, aws-codestar

I am using AWS Code star and using Express Web service template. Code star create Lambda and create API Gateway API. The api works, it returns what I want. I am trying to enable to CORS, through API gateway,

**API GateWay -> API -> resouce -> Actions -> Enable CORS**.

It fails on setting CORS on options as integration response is not generated for proxy.  Here are the images.
[image]

[image]

I think I have to configure this through YAML to generate integration response on options and GET.

Here is my **YAML**

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
- AWS::CodeStar

Parameters:
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: AWS CodeStar projectID used to associate new resources to team members

Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
  GetById:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /api/getById
            Method: get
```

Here is my Lambda Handler.

```
    'use strict';

const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```

I would appreciate if some one can help me how can i adjust the CloudFormation Template.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add headers to a integration response for proxy integrations. You will need to add the CORS headers in the response from lambda as

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your CloudFormation template. If you are using Serverless has an option to enable CORS with "cors: true" like below:

```
functions:
  suggest:
    handler: shopping-service.suggestWardrobe
    timeout: 20
    memorySize: 256
    name: demo-shopping-service
    description: Provides wardrobe suggestions based on a given Location

    events:
     - http:
        path: suggest
        method: get
        cors: true
```

But that only applies to the API endpoint and not to the API lambda proxy.

You have to explicitly set the header in the lambda callback in order for CORS to work.

```
let payload = {
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
};
callback(null, payload);
```

You must also return a valid statusCode and body along with the headers, or the API will fail to transform your lambda response to an API response.